# How to prevent CLion from debugging into C++ source files

Tags: clion

So when I am debugging my program in CLion I use F7 to see where my program travels step by step. But sometimes, the program moves into source files like "unique_ptr.h", which I am not interested in seeing. Is there a way to prevent the debugger from inspecting those files? I only want to see my own source code.

Comment: Hello and welcome! What have you tried? What have you found in your own research? Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to better help others help you.

Comment: Would `F8` (step over) and `SHIFT`+`F8` (step out) be feasible for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you use LLBD just edit ~/.lldbinit. And add a line like

`settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ^(std::|boost::shared_ptr)`

This prevents from stepping into std:: stuff, and also does not step into shared_ptr.

If you use GDB you can use its skipping functionality  https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html